# How can I add group numbers to sequential records in SQL Server 2012 when a column value changes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, window-functions

I've been playing with window functions in SQL Server 2012 and can't get this to work, as I'm hoping to avoid a cursor and going row by row. My problem is that I need to add a group number to each record. The tricky part is that the group number has to increment each time a column value changes, even if it changes back to a value that existed before earlier in the sequence of records.

Here's an example of the data and my desired outcome:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#data') is not null 
    drop table #data

create table #data
(
    id int identity(1,1)
    ,mytime datetime
    ,distance int
    ,direction varchar(20)
)

insert into #data (mytime, distance, direction) 
values 
 ('2016-01-01 08:00',10,'North')
,('2016-01-01 08:30',18,'North')
,('2016-01-01 09:00',15,'North')
,('2016-01-01 09:30',12,'South')
,('2016-01-01 10:00',16,'South')
,('2016-01-01 10:30',45,'North')
,('2016-01-01 11:00',23,'North')
,('2016-01-01 11:30',14,'South')
,('2016-01-01 12:00',40,'South')
```

Desired outcome:

```
mytime              Distance    Direction   GroupNumber
--------------------------------------------------------
2016-01-01 8:00     10          North       1
2016-01-01 8:30     18          North       1
2016-01-01 9:00     15          North       1
2016-01-01 9:30     12          South       2
2016-01-01 10:00    16          South       2
2016-01-01 10:30    45          North       3
2016-01-01 11:00    23          North       3
2016-01-01 11:30    14          South       4
2016-01-01 12:00    40          South       4
```

Is this possible using window functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                CASE
                  WHEN LAG(direction)
                         OVER (ORDER BY ID) = direction THEN 0
                  ELSE 1
                END AS Flag
         FROM   #data)
SELECT mytime,
       Distance,
       Direction,
       SUM(Flag) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS GroupNumber
FROM   T
```

The above assumes `Direction` doesn't contain any `NULLs`. It would need a minor adjustment if this is possible. But you would also need to define whether or not two consecutive `NULL` should be treated as equal (assuming this was the case then the below variant would work)

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                prev = LAG(direction) OVER (ORDER BY ID),
                rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)
         FROM   #data)
SELECT mytime,
       Distance,
       Direction,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rn > 1 AND EXISTS(SELECT prev 
                                       INTERSECT 
                                       SELECT Direction) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS GroupNumber
FROM   T 
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: That's really nice.

Comment: This is great.  I think I have some NULLs or blank values for the direction field, but will probably be filtering those out.